# Is there an easy way to check for an existing ActiveRecord object with exactly the same associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to create a set of models that represents a bundle of products. When I create a new bundle, I'd like to check if a matching bundle already exists so I can re-use it.

### Models

```rb
class Bundle < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

```rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :bundles
end
```

### Migration

```rb
class CreateBundles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :bundles
    create_table :products
    create_join_table :bundles, :products
    add_index :bundles_products, [:bundle_id, :product_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

### What I've Tried

First I tried using `find_or_create_by` but it did not like the HABTM association:

```rb
Bundle.find_or_create_by!(products: Product.where(id: [1, 2, 3]))
# ActiveRecord::UnknownPrimaryKey (Unknown primary key for table bundles_products in model Bundles::HABTM_Products.)
```

Based on some other questions I managed to create some methods that achieve the behaviour I am after. This works but given how horrible it looks this is certainly the wrong path:

```rb
class Bundle < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products

  def self.containing_exactly(products)
    product_ids = products.pluck(:id)
    where('bundles.id = (
      SELECT bundles_products.bundle_id
      FROM bundles_products 
      JOIN products on bundles_products.product_id = products.id
      GROUP BY bundles_products.bundle_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN products.id IN (?) THEN products.id END) = ? 
      AND COUNT(CASE WHEN products.id NOT IN (?) THEN 1 END) = 0
      LIMIT 1)', product_ids, product_ids.size, product_ids).first
    end
  
  def self.create_for(products)
    containing_exactly(products) || create!(products: products)
  end
end
```

```rb
Bundle.create_for(Product.first(2)) # Creates a new bundle with the first two products
Bundle.create_for(Product.first(2)) # Returns the previous bundle since it has the exact same products
```

Is there an easier way to find existing bundles that match a particular set of products or is there another way to approach these models?

Using mysql for the database

Comment: are you using Postgres?

Comment: Added this to the question, using mysql.

Comment: you may have a typo... `product_ids` is not used in the query

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix it now. Bundle ids should be product ids. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way in Rails, you will have to write your own query. You've pretty much got it, I would only suggest cleaning it up:

```
where(<<~SQL, product_ids).first
  bundles.id = (
    select bundle_id
    from bundles_products
    group by bundle_id
    having count(product_id) = count(case when product_id in (?) then 1 else 0 end)
    limit 1
  )
SQL
```

P. S. If that ever becomes a performance bottleneck, you could always add a cache column to "bundles" table. But you will need to make sure to always fill it in.

```
# Migration
add_column :bundles, :products_hash, :string

# Model
def self.create_for(products)
  products_hash = Digest::SHA1.base64digest(products.map(&:id).join(","))
  Bundle.find_or_create_by!(products_hash: products_hash) do
    bundle.products = products
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you add a uniqueness constraint on the products_hash to enforce duplications aren't added?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
BundlesProducts.where(product_id: product_ids)
  .group_by(&:bundle_id)
  .select { |k, v| v.map(&:product_id) == product_ids}.keys
```

but this would requite to define the `BundlesProducts` model, also the problem here is I do memory processing for the retrieved records.